# I am filtering a SharePoint list based on two criteria: "Assigned To" and "status".What is the CAML Query for it?

Tags: sharepoint-online, caml-query

The list should be filtered like this SQL given below:

`select * from SPLIST where status="complete" AND Assigned To="Samrat Sarkar"`

I have this CAML query but it doesnt work:

```
"<View>
  <Query>
    <Where>
      <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name='Status'/><Value Type='Text'>" + "Open" + "</Value>
      </Eq>
       <And>
      <Eq>
        <FieldRef Name='Assigned To'/><Value Type='Text'>" + "Samrat Sarkar" 
         + "</Value>
      </Eq>
      </And>
    </Where>
  </Query>
 </View>";
```

Please help.

Comment: Change `Assigned To` to `Assigned_x0020_To` (which is the internal name)

Comment: The internal name is `AssignedTo` (assuming the OOTB Assigned To column)

Comment: good catch @theChrisKent , I was assuming the space encoding.

Answer (score 4):

Refer below query.

And one more thing as Mike commented, you will have to use internal name of you field (e.g. `Assigned_x0020_To`)

```
"<View>
   <Query>
      <Where>
         <And>
            <Eq>
               <FieldRef Name='Status' />
               <Value Type='Text'>Open</Value>
            </Eq>
            <Eq>
               <FieldRef Name='Assigned_x0020_To' />
               <Value Type='Text'>Samrat Sarkar</Value>
            </Eq>
         </And>
      </Where>
   </Query>
</View>";
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<View>
  <Query>
    <Where>
      <And>
        <Eq>
          <FieldRef Name='Status'/><Value Type='Choice'>Open</Value>
        </Eq>
        <Eq>
          <FieldRef Name='AssignedTo'/><Value Type='UserMulti'>Samrat Sarkar</Value>
        </Eq>
      </And>
    </Where>
  </Query>
 </View>
```

The `And` needs to wrap the 2 conditions. Additionally, the internal name of the Assigned To column is `AssignedTo` and it is a multi person field (`UserMulti`) assuming this is a tasks list. The Status column is also of type `Choice`.

Answer (score 0):

When using CAML queries I would advise to use a builder, just like Microsoft also advises here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647340.aspx

There are also others out there if you search a bit.